# Proxy authentication error in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I typed the command

```
sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

And typed the export statement as

```
export http_proxy="username: password@proxyhost:port"
```

But after saving it gave a warning message as

```
set document meta data failed 
gedit spell language not supported
gedit encoding not supported
gedit position not supported
```

When I try apt-get update it still shows proxy authentication error

Comment: The warning is possibly related to this [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) - rather than anything to do with the proxy setting

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing cntlm to automatically handle your proxy settings:

```
supo apt install cntlm
sudo nano /etc/cntlm.conf
```

From here edit the following fields to give your credentials:

```
Username username
Domain proxydomain
Paswword pwd 

[...]

Proxy proxyaddress:3128
Noproxy localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*
Listen proxyport
```